# How to restrict a not empty field in ruby on rails active record where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to ruby and want to restrict records that have not empty `:c` field values as follows.

```
Foo.where(:a => "x", :b => "y", :c ?? "")
```

My problem is that I not know which operator `??` I have to use for that or if an operator for that exists at all.

As I am writing the question I came accross the `where chains` in the [ruby on rails api documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/). If I write the where clause as follows I get what I want.

```
Foo.where(:a => "x", :b => "y").where.not(:c => "")
```

So far so good the where chain gives me what I want. But is there a way to use an operator `??` to bring it all together in a simple where clause statement as in my first example?

Comment: Personally, I feel your working example is the clearest usage, and what I'd go with.

Comment: I would avoid mixing up SQL syntax with ActiveRecrod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have valid syntax, you have to use `=>` in place of `??`. That's because you are passing a hash to `where` method.

As you mentioned, you can chain `where` and `where.not`. Another solution is to use one `where` as below:

```
Foo.where("a = ? and b = ? and c != ''", 'x', 'y')
```